# Search all columns for a given value in SQL Server and return only exact match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table called `PRODUCTDATA` which has the following data:

[image]

To get the `prodctunits` from `PRODUCTDATA` table from `ET`, P1 and ML column values that can be present in any of the columns i.e product1, product2 and product3.

My query is

```
select Productunits 
from PRODUCTDATA 
where 
    'P1' IN (PRODUCT1, Product2, product3) AND 
    'ET' IN (PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2, PRODUCT3) AND
    'ML' IN (PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2, PRODUCT3);
```

which returns 20 as product Units

However If my query is

```
select Productunits 
from PRODUCTDATA 
where  
    'ML' IN (PRODUCT1, Product2, product3) and 
    'P1' IN (PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2, PRODUCT3);
```

it should return only 15 as `Productunits`, but this query returns 2 rows, 20 and 15.

Similarly if I do a search for P1 then it should return the lower value i.w 8 only from the `PRODUCTDATA` table.

How to achieve this?

Comment: i created a sql fiddle...it seems to handle nulls right - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6e98b/1    im seeing the expected behavior to be honest...not what you are saying

Comment: CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
  PRODUCT1 VARCHAR(50),
  PRODUCT2 VARCHAR(50),
  PRODUCT3 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO PRODUCT SELECT 'ML', 'ET', NULL;
INSERT INTO PRODUCT SELECT 'ML', 'ET', NULL;
INSERT INTO PRODUCT SELECT 'ML', 'GG', 'YY';
INSERT INTO PRODUCT SELECT 'ML', 'GG', 'ZZ';   SELECT * FROM PRODUCT
WHERE 'ML' IN (PRODUCT1,PRODUCT2,PRODUCT3)
    AND 'GG' IN (PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2, PRODUCT3)
    AND 'YY' IN (PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2, PRODUCT3);

Comment: @Ctznkane525
My current query handles it effective , what I'm looking is the exact search

Comment: One of the worse formatted questions I have seen from a user over 1000 rep.  Not buying SQL is returning the wrong answer.    VTC

Comment: @Paparazzi
I apologize for the bad formatting but I tried to insert an image to show the table data and it messed up my formatting , I apologize again

Comment: You think a less restrictive where should produce less results.   The image did not kill the text formatting.

Comment: agree , i will make sure formatting is correct going forward

Comment: Fix it now would be going forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly test the other column for not having other values.  Here is one method:

```
select Productunits
from PRODUCTDATA
where 'ML' in (product1, product2, product3) and
      'P1' in (product1, product2, product3) and
      (product1 in ('ML', 'P1') or product1 is null) and
      (product2 in ('ML', 'P1') or product2 is null) and
      (product3 in ('ML', 'P1') or product3 is null) ;
```

Incidentally, this query would be simpler if your data structure were normalized and you had one row per product.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon  Your SQL query works however I have 1 more question , How can I return the lowest value in case of P1 , I tried hard but couldn't come up with solution . Thank you for your time

Comment: @ronan . . . You could use `select min(ProductUnits)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Productunits 
from PRODUCTDATA 
where  'ML' IN ( PRODUCT1,Product2,product3) 
and 'P1' IN (PRODUCT1,PRODUCT2,PRODUCT3);
```

This query is searching for 'ML' in ANY of the first three columns and P1 in ANY of the first three columns.  'ML' and 'PL' show up in both rows 3 and 4. So the query returns two results.

Assuming the row # is the Primary Key or unique identifier for the table then you can use the query below.

```
SELECT Productunits
FROM PRODUCTDATA
WHERE id = 5
```

To pull this data out without a primary key try using CONCAT... Note that the concat syntax varies with the type of DB you are using.  Below is MySQL syntax.

```
SELECT Productunits
FROM PRODUCTDATA
where 'MLP1' in (SELECT concat(product2, product3) from productdata)
```